# Is there any separate Java api for encoding the string and as well as decoding

Tags: java

Is there any separate Java API for encoding the string as well as decoding the same encoded string?

Please give any suggestions if you have

Comment: How do you want to encode the string?

Comment: Thats most important question by Henry.

Comment: actually when user gives a password from front end my java class handles it and stores it in db. but while i am saving i need to encode the password and save because the db admin should not be able view user password

Comment: To store password information in the DB you probably want to hash them using a message digest function like SHA1 or SHA256. You should also use salt. See for example https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: This question is too vague. Encoding != Encrypting != Hashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check this docs of  [Base64 coding by Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

And we have sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and sun.misc.BASE64Decoder given by Sun but better to go with Apache.

And if you want to encrypt your string if it is password then :

MD5 must be good enough for you I imagine? You can achieve it with [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

`MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");`

There are also other algorithms listed [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/CryptoSpec.html#AppA).

And here's an third party version of it, if you really want:
[Fast MD5](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php)

Comment: do u know about RSA algorithm for encryption?

Comment: Follow this link for same http://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/rsa-encryption-example/

Comment: Check the latest answer

Comment: Be careful, Base64 encoding is useless for securing passwords in a DB.

Comment: Agree with you henry. But he doesnt clear the requirement so i thought that....he said about encoding and not encryption

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Refer this [example to encode decode string](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-encode-decode-string-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have for example [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) in the JDK.